# Hooking into a fragment's lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building a re-usable component that should do something on a fragment's `onResume` and another on `onPause`.

I am trying to take a composition over inheritance approach, so that consumers don't need to inherit from my fragment and can rather do something like `this.myComponent.registerFragment(this)` in the fragment constructor. From that point on, `myComponent` will take care of things on its own.

I am wondering what the best approach to observe/hook into the fragment lifecycle is. I currently have a `HookableFragment` base fragment that allows registering listeners for its lifecycle methods. It works, but it still requires inheritance even though it's more generic than a base class specifically for my component.

I am wondering if using a child fragment would be a better solution. If `myComponent` was a (UI less) fragment, would it provide the lifecycle-hooking functionality I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested Fragments should support the same lifecycle-hooking as Fragments in Activities do, so there should be no problem with this approach.

Just keep in mind to use the Support Libraries (and that the consumers also have to do this), because the `getChildFragmentManager()` Method is only supported since Android 4.2 otherwise.

Another approach would be that the Fragment has to call through to your component in the `onResume` and `onPause` methods.

Comment: I ended up calling onResume and onPause manually on my component from the fragment. Good enough for the amount of effort I want to put in now. Thanks!